# openApiGenerator 6.6.0 runs out of heap space when trying to generate swagger.json code

Tags: gradle, swagger, openapi-generator, openapi-generator-cli

We are migrating from springboot 2.5 to springboot 3.1.2 and we are also changing our generator from org.hidetake.swagger.generator to 'org.openapi.generator'. We also switched from java 8 to 17 What is the reason for the following error?

> - Exception is:
>   org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':openApiGenerate'.
>   at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.lambda$executeIfValid$1(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:142)
>   at org.gradle.internal.Try$Failure.ifSuccessfulOrElse(Try.java:282)
>   at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeIfValid(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:140)
>   at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:128)
>   at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.execute(CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.java:77)
>   at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.FinalizePropertiesTaskExecuter.execute(FinalizePropertiesTaskExecuter.java:46)
>   at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskExecutionModeExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskExecutionModeExecuter.java:51)
>   at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:57)
>   at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:57)
>   at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:36)
>   at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.executeTask(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:77)
>   at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.call(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:55)
>   at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.call(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:52)
>   at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:204)
>   at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:199)
>   at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:66)
>   at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
>   at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:157)
>   at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
>   at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.call(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:53)
>   at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.call(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:73)
>   at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter.execute(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:52)
>   at org.gradle.execution.plan.LocalTaskNodeExecutor.execute(LocalTaskNodeExecutor.java:69)
>   at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$InvokeNodeExecutorsAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:322)
>   at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$InvokeNodeExecutorsAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:309)
>   at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$BuildOperationAwareExecutionAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:302)
>   at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$BuildOperationAwareExecutionAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:288)
>   at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.execute(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:462)
>   at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.run(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:379)
>   at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:64)
>   at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:49)
>   Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
>   at org.openapitools.codegen.DefaultCodegen.updateAllModels(DefaultCodegen.java:632)
>   at org.openapitools.codegen.DefaultGenerator.generateModels(DefaultGenerator.java:529)
>   at org.openapitools.codegen.DefaultGenerator.generate(DefaultGenerator.java:946)
>   at org.openapitools.generator.gradle.plugin.tasks.GenerateTask.doWork(GenerateTask.kt:841)
>   at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>   at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
>   at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>   at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:125)
>   at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.doExecute(StandardTaskAction.java:58)
>   at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:51)
>   at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:29)
>   at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.TaskExecution$3.run(TaskExecution.java:236)
>   at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:29)
>   at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:26)
>   at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:66)
>   at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
>   at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:157)
>   at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
>   at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.run(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:47)
>   at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:68)
>   at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.TaskExecution.executeAction(TaskExecution.java:221)
>   at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.TaskExecution.executeActions(TaskExecution.java:204)
>   at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.TaskExecution.executeWithPreviousOutputFiles(TaskExecution.java:187)
>   at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.TaskExecution.execute(TaskExecution.java:165)
>   at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ExecuteStep.executeInternal(ExecuteStep.java:89)
>   at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ExecuteStep.access$000(ExecuteStep.java:40)

I have gone through https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator/issues/11195 and can confirm using the validator and it says that our spec is good.

I have found the route cause of the error and its got to do with the openapi normalizer. I need this functionality. How can I fix this? github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator/issues/15939

Comment: Have you tried increasing the heap space?

Comment: Yes I did. I suspect is being a swagger.json issue as it worked for a different project

Comment: So, did increasing the heap solve your issue? If not, have you tried maxing out you machine's memory to see if that works? Are you using the newest version of the openapi generator?

Comment: @LeonardBrünings Increasing the heap did not solve the problem. I tried maxing out and it is the newest version of openapi generator. I believe it is an issue with my swagger.json but the validator doesnt pick it up

Comment: I have found the route cause of the error and its got to do with the openapi normalizer. I need this functionality. How can I fix this?

https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator/issues/15939